# Inspect element on Google and Opera false size on tags

Tags: html, css

The question is if its bad coding or inspect element is bugged on Opera and Google Chrome.

If you inspect element on the menu on the right not the top one you will see the a tag has 0 px 0 px while in firebug a tag appears as the size of the span same in internet explorer appears the same as in firebug.

My real question is the inspect element not working properly? Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/sMygA

```
<div class="menutop2">
                    <ul class="list2">
                        <li><a href="site1/services"><span>Your Services</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="site1/industry"><span>Your Industry</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="site1/insights"><span>Sharing Insights</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="site1/client_stories"><span>Client Stories</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="site1/expert_client"><span class="liwbg">Expert Client</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a false size

The "a" element is an inline element, so it does not really have a "box". Saying that it have no size at all may seems wrong (since you 'see' it uses space) but it can be considered right according to the specification (can't find a link right now).
Reporting it's size as the size of it's content maybe is not so conformant to the specification, but the inspector is a tool oriented to help on the developement and makes sense to say how much visual space it occupy (even if it's not really/properly a box) if it looks like a box.

So both answers (0x0 and #x#) could be considered right.

If in the inspector you are using you change the "display" property of the 'a' element and set it to "inline-block" you'll check that both of them report the same size, because it will really have a "box".

When the link is just a word maybe it's not very obvious but consider this code:

```
<p style="background:grey">This is a paragraph with a link. <a href="#" style="background:yellow">It's an inline element</a> that does not have a bounding box.</p>
```

When the paragraph is rendered it cloud be in a single line and still think there *is* a box, but when it render to something like that:

[image: Sample inline element running throw two text lines]

...you can see it cristal clear. It'n is not a box, it's is inline content.

Comment: Still inline element have a width and height not 0 height 0 width so still somewhere something is wrong. I can make a div inline element and still it will have widht and height. Anyway it's a weird thing. I accept you'r answer :).